# Update with subquery get error: "The multi-part identifier could not be bound." (Sql Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to update a set of records in a table with values from another set of records in the same table.  When I run this query, I get error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "t.com" could not be bound.

Code:

```
update tphase
set
   t.com = t.com + b.com,
   t.direct = t.direct + b.direct,
   t.fee = t.fee + b.fee,
   t.fringe = t.fringe + b.fringe,
   t.fte = t.fte + b.fte,
   t.ganda = t.ganda + b.ganda,
   t.hours = t.hours + b.hours,
   t.overhead = t.overhead + b.overhead,
   t.fccmga = t.fccmga + b.fccmga,
   t.fccmoh = t.fccmoh + b.fccmoh,
   t.lbroh = t.lbroh + b.lbroh,
   t.ms = t.ms + b.ms
from
   tphase t 
inner join
   (select *
    from tphase
    where program = 'xenon' and
          class = 'earned' and
          df_date > '2013-05-03'        
   ) as b on t.program = b.program and
             t.cawpid = b.cawpid and
             t.class = b.class and
             t.cecode = b.cecode
where
   t.program = 'xenon' and
   t.class = 'earned' and
   t.df_date = '2013-05-03' ;
```

Comment: Can you post the table structure of `tphase`?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE TPHASE
 (
 PROGRAM nvarchar(22),
 CAWPID int,
 CECODE nvarchar(59),
 CLASS nvarchar(20),
 DF_DATE datetime,
 BATCHNO int,
 COM decimal(21, 6),
 DIRECT decimal(21, 6),
 FEE decimal(21, 6),
 FRINGE decimal(21, 6),
 FTE decimal(21, 6),
 GANDA decimal(21, 6),
 HOURS decimal(21, 6),
 OVERHEAD decimal(21, 6),
 FCCMGA decimal(21, 6),
 FCCMOH decimal(21, 6),
 LBROH decimal(21, 6),
 MS decimal(21, 6)
 )`

Answer (score 3):

if you're giving tphase the alias t, you need to reference that alias in the update statement, too,

```
UPDATE t
set
    t.com = t.com + b.com, 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that there is no column named `com` in the `tphase` table.  You will either need to remove that reference, or change it to the correct column name.

Comment: Might not be getting that far since it errors out with t before.

Comment: No there's not...  If you want to prove me wrong then show me the create table script.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TPHASE](
 [PROGRAM] [nvarchar](22) NOT NULL,
 [CAWPID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CECODE] [nvarchar](59) NOT NULL,
 [CLASS] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [DF_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [BATCHNO] [int] NOT NULL,
 [COM] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [DIRECT] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [FEE] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [FRINGE] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [FTE] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [GANDA] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [HOURS] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [OVERHEAD] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [FCCMGA] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL,
 [FCCMOH] [decimal](21, 6) NOT NULL

Comment: the problem wasn't caused by referencing a column that didn't exist.  It was caused by using "update tphase" rather than "update t"